# How do I get the source IP address from a datagram's IP header with Winsock?

Tags: c++, windows, winsock

I have a port that is bind()'d to INADDR_ANY.  I am receiving datagrams successfully.  After receipt, I need to read the IP header to get the source IP address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe you can get it if you're using the standard recv or read function calls.  The recvfrom call as follows:

```
int recvfrom(
  __in         SOCKET s,
  __out        char *buf,
  __in         int len,
  __in         int flags,
  __out        struct sockaddr *from,
  __inout_opt  int *fromlen
);
```

includes a structure (the second to last field above) which will receive the source address which you can examine for whatever purposes you desire.